# REST API Filter by multilookup property

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, rest, listdata.svc

Having an Activities list with a column called Engineer of type lookup that allow multiple values. How to build a call to listdata.svc in order to get only activities that are asigned to an Engineer with Id equal to 10 for example ?

I've tried :

```
http://myserver:10113/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Activities()?$filter=Engineer/Id eq '10'&$expand=Engineer&$select=Id,Name,StartDate,EndDate,Engineer/Id,Engineer/FirstName, Engineer/LastName
```

For this I receive thet 'Id' property do not exist. I think this is because Engineer is a colection.

Or if somewone know how to do this using LINQ and WCF Data Services in Visual Studio 2010 ? Then I will use Fiddler to see the call translation.

Thank you !

Comment: Same issue here... did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your lookupfield can accept multiple values you cannot make a filter on a column which is contained in this lookup.

I had the same issue.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you are using Looking up Fields you have to use like this

```
&$expand=Engineer/Id&
```

Similarly for other Fields as well. you can try the same.